# MobileFirst 7.0 WLAPP deployment not synchronizing on other application server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are using MobileFirst 7.0 and running on 2 Tomcat application servers. When we deploy new WLAPP, it will deploy on 1 of the app server but not synchronizing to other app server until we restart the tomcat service.

Is there a flag / option to automatically synchronize on both app servers?

Thank you.

Best regards,
JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronization should happen automatically and it is controlled by property
*cluster.data.synchronization.taskFrequencyInSeconds* in the server.xml. Try reducing this value if it set too high.

Also check the property *ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid* to make sure it is specified correctly as per the documentation below

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html

Comment: Thank you for the response Srinivas. I will verify the entries.

Comment: After verifying our server.xml, I found out that we haven't specified cluster.data.synchronization.taskFrequencyInSeconds, which I presumed it is taking the default value which is 2 seconds. 

Do we need to specifically include this property in our application context? 

Thank you.

Comment: After further checking, I also found that in our server.xml, the topology.clustermode value for both application server is 'Standalone'. Does it need to be set 'Farm'? Is this affecting the issue reported above? Thanks

Comment: if it is a farm set up then you need to change this topology.clustermode appropriately. Let me know if this helped resolve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Update: Changing the topology.clustermode to 'Farm' resolves the issue. Thanks